# Test for Palindrome using a recursive function in C

Tags: c, function, recursion, logic

I tried to write the program for testing a string if it's a palindrome or not, but I always get the output as it's not one. What's wrong with my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int is_palindrome(int start, int end, char *str)
{
    if (str[start] != str[end])
        return 0;
    else if (start == end)
        return 1;
    else
        return is_palindrome(++start, --end, str);

    return 0;

}
int main()
{
    char str[20];
    int length,start=0,end=length-1;
    int result;
    printf("Enter the String.\n");
    fgets( str, sizeof( str ), stdin );
    length = strlen(str);

    if(is_palindrome(start,end,str))
        printf("It's a palindrome!\n");
    else
        printf("It's not a palindrome! \n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Step through the code in a debugger, line by line. And use a string that you _know_ is a palindrome, preferably a short one so it's quicker.

Comment: `int length,start=0,end=length-1;` length does not have a value (yet) here.

Comment: `length` isn't set to anything, therefore `end` is garbage.

Comment: I fixed that, still I'm getting the same output.

Comment: What happens when you debug the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two main issues,

**1)** You are initializing `end` using `length` without first initializing `length`:

```
length = strlen(str);
/* initialize end here */
```

**2)** You are not considering the newline you get at the end of the string from `fgets`:

```
end = length - 2; /* don't include the newline */
```

Answer (score 3):

What happens when `++start` and `--end` pass each other?

```
else if (start == end)
```

Should be `>=`.

Answer (score 0):

In this `is_palindrome()` function you must need to check it otherwise it will not work for the even number character of palindrome word

```
if(start>end)
    return 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

On the line with  `if(start==end)` there is logical error.

This is caused by the last recursive call, where the value of last and end will always be same i.e they both will be at the center of the array.  Consequently the function `is_palindrome()` will always return `1` and the output will always be `It's a palindrome!`