# Recursive function finding Palindrome

Tags: c, recursion, palindrome

May be you can tell me the way, that I can start with, at least. I can use only C language. The task have very specific limitations and I can't break them in any way. The task is:

- Write recursive function that checks if string is Palindrome.
- Can use `strlen()` only once in function.
- Can't use any loops or functions based on loops.
- Can use only one transition in recursive function.
- Can change the string, but only if it will come back in the end of
  function.
- Declaration of function is: `int palindrom(char* str);`
- I started to write, but have no ideas anymore:

  ```
  #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <string.h>

  int palindrom(char* str)
  {
      int len = strlen(str);
      if (str[0] != str[len - 1]) return 0;

  }

  int main(void)
  {
      char string1[] = "ROTATOR";
      char string2[] = "8536358";
      char string3[] = "Palindrome";
      if (palindrom(string1)) printf("%s is Palindrome\n", string1);
      else printf("%s is not Palindrome\n", string1);
      if (palindrom(string2)) printf("%s is Palindrome\n", string2);
      else printf("%s is not Palindrome\n", string2);
      if (palindrom(string3)) printf("%s is Palindrome\n", string3);
      else printf("%s is not Palindrome\n", string3);
      return 0;
  }
  ```

Comment: Wow, you got writer's block fast.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16062723/test-for-palindrome-using-a-recursive-function-in-c).

Comment: Googling 'C Recursive function finding Palindrome',  ie. your title prepended with 'C', gives; 'About 92,300 results'.

Comment: Don't know why you so fast going to blame people, but I'm new in this area. I saw that topic and it's not the thing what I need. My code should answer all point that I wrote.

Comment: I suggest - in general - when you have a task with several limitations, you solve it first *without* those limitations, to familiarise yourself with the task and how it can be solved. Then you move to the restrictions. Most code is not written by sitting down and writing it, but by a **process** of development.

Comment: ^ OP clearly says he knows how to do it without the constraints @WeatherVane

Comment: @RaviSankarRaju yes he wrote that in comment some time after my remark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clue to how to solve is in the restriction: *Can change the string, but only if it will come back in the end of function.* That condition is checked by printing the result.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int palindrom(char* str)
{
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    int res;
    if(len < 2) {
        return 1;                   // cannot shorten: must be success
    }
    if(str[0] != str[len - 1]) {    // make palindrome test
        return 0;
    }

    str[len - 1] = '\0';            // shorten the string at the back
    res = palindrom(str + 1);       // recurse woth string shortened at the front
    str[len - 1] = str[0];          // replace last char (we know it's the same)
    return res;
}

int main(void)
{
    char string1[] = "ROTATOR";
    char string2[] = "8536358";
    char string3[] = "Palindrome";
    char string4[] = "A";
    char *wrd[] = { "not ", "" };

    printf("%s is %sa Palindrome\n", string1, wrd[ palindrom(string1) ]);
    printf("%s is %sa Palindrome\n", string2, wrd[ palindrom(string2) ]);
    printf("%s is %sa Palindrome\n", string3, wrd[ palindrom(string3) ]);
    printf("%s is %sa Palindrome\n", string4, wrd[ palindrom(string4) ]);

    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
ROTATOR is a Palindrome
8536358 is a Palindrome
Palindrome is not a Palindrome
A is a Palindrome
```

Comment: @StanislavRyzhkov thank you for your vote. I have just simplified the chararcter replacement, as we know the first char == last char.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Very much! It's look like as I tried to do. As I said to Ravi, I don't sure if I understood right the limitation of calling to recursion, if I can call unlimited times or only once. If it's once then it's seems me too strange for using recursion at all. I will talk with my lecturer about this.

Comment: If you only call it once, it is not recursion. A recursive function calls itself, and **must** have an exit condition to prevent stack overflow.

Comment: @Weather Vane your solution is right! Thank you very much, I missed last character cutting in my code, so yours has improved it and there is limitation only for one recursive cycle  over the string.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will work ?

```
Something like this will work ?

#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

bool palindrom_helper(char* str, int first, int last)
{
    if(first >= last)
        return true;
    if (str[first] != str[last]) 
        return false;
    return (palindrom(str, first+1, last-1));

}

bool palindrom(char* str)
{
    return palindrom_helper(str, 0, strlen(str)-1);
}

int main(void)
{
    char string1[] = "ROTATOR";
    char string2[] = "8536358";
    char string3[] = "Palindrome";
    if (palindrom(string1)) printf("%s is Palindrome\n", string1);
    else printf("%s is not Palindrome\n", string1);
    if (palindrom(string2)) printf("%s is Palindrome\n", string2);
    else printf("%s is not Palindrome\n", string2);
    if (palindrom(string3)) printf("%s is Palindrome\n", string3);
    else printf("%s is not Palindrome\n", string3);
    return 0;
}
```

you should use the strlen function only once. so you cannot use it inside the function that's being called recursively.

what i did here is to initialize first and last to 0 and len-1 and then recurse with (first+1, last-1).

if the function finds even one pair of unmatching letters, it'd return false. else it'd continue until they reach the center together (odd length string) or cross each other (even length string) and then return true (because that'd mean they did not see any unmatching letter on their path)

Also, i dont understand what you mean by single transition in the recursive function ?

Comment: *Can use `strlen()` only once in function.* There are 3 in `main`

Comment: pretty sure that constraint is one strlen usage per palindrom() call. no way you can check if 10 strings are palindromes without atleast calling strlen 10 times.

Comment: Thank you for your work! But, as I wrote, I have very specific limitations, I can't get any other `int`s for input in my function. I can solve the task without those limitations, but with it don't have any idea :(

Comment: can we define another helper function or does that hurt the constraint too ?

Comment: I can use another functions, but functions without loops.

Comment: how about this updated solution. have the signature as it is and delegate the worker to the helper function. sort of a hack, maybe. but the conditions being a little weird, i guess its ok

Comment: calling palindrom_helper(str,0,strlen(str)-1) from palindrom so that the signature is unaffected..

Comment: Ye, that's it, it will be strange and useless to call palindrom() first, yes it's answered to constraint of declaration, but I can do only one recursive transition. I think use roundabout way is not the solution.

Comment: Yes, but you are still misreading the conditions. *Declaration of function is: `int palindrom(char* str);`* meaning, the recursive function in the question.

Comment: If you had put the prototype `bool palindrom(char* str);` the compiler would have rejected your program error. But surely you got a warning?

Comment: @StanislavRyzhkov can you explain what you mean by recursive transition ? there's only one transition into a recursive function, right ?

Comment: May be I did not understand it right, it's in hebrew :)
But there is said: Can use only one recursive transition on the string.

Comment: This can be 2 way of understanding:
1. I can call to palndrom() only once and must get the answer if it's palindrom.
2. I call to palindrom() without limitation but only once on all over the string and sending to it every time string without "borders" and then it's very easy to implement:
`int palindrom(char* str)
 {
int len = strlen(str);
if (str[0] != str[len - 1]) return 0;
palindrom(str + 1);
return 1;
}`